# ETH-Brownie How can I import from github when the version number includes letters and numbers?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, brownie, defi

Normally you can import npm style via a brownie-config.yaml file like so:

```
dependencies:
    - uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1

compiler:
    solc:
        remappings:
            - 'uniswap=uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1'
```

However, I am having trouble importing the Uniswap/v2-periphery because the only tag is 1.0.0-beta.0 shown here. I've tried importing in the following ways with no success:

```
dependencies:
    - uniswap/v2-periphery@1.0.0

compiler:
    solc:
        remappings:
            - 'uniswap=uniswap/v2-periphery@1.0.0'
```

AND

```
dependencies:
    - uniswap/v2-periphery@1.0.0-beta.0

compiler:
    solc:
        remappings:
            - 'uniswap=uniswap/v2-periphery@1.0.0-beta.0'
```

Neither work. How can I import this repo? https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do exactly as you have here, you add the whole release string.

For example:

```yaml
dependencies:
    - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.2.1-solc-0.7
compiler:
    solc:
        remappings:
            - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.2.1-solc-0.7"
```

The reason that yours isn't working right now is that https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery doesn't have any releases, it only has tags.

What you could do then, is fork the repo, make a release yourself and point to your own release until they actually release something.